# Why does recreating H2 database reduce the size drastically

Tags: database, h2

I have a small database (6 tables, max rows of 70,000) which was taking up 16GB of disk space. I couldn't figure out why the size was so big. I tried running `compact shutdown`  which actually increased the size by a few megabytes instead of reducing it. I tried deleting rows, which made almost no difference.

Then I tried creating a script, dropping everything, re-creating the database from the script:

```
SCRIPT TO 'mydb.sql';
DROP ALL OBJECTS;
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'mydb.sql';
```

The size of the database went from **16GB to 6MB**.

I am trying to understand what is going on in the background to cause this huge difference in size.

I am using H2 Embedded database version 1.4.192

How do I fix this issue in production? Is creating a cron job that recreates the database every month the only solution?

Comment: Related information is being discussed here: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/301. The H2 DB seems to grow indefinitely under certain circumstances, and the only way to counter this seems to be your approach.

Comment: SHUTDOWN DEFRAG command worked for me.